# iOs focus on input and open virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, ios

**What I want to achieve:**

I want a dropdown with a search field where the focus automatically jumps to the input field and the virtual keyboard of iOs appears for the input.

The existing element with dropdown is created in a WordPress builder with a container div. There i added my searchform.

[image]

**Where it works:**

Focusing works in all desktop browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Safari without any problems.

**iOs won't work:**

Only under iOs there is no focus and no call of the virtual keyboard.

I have already tried several solutions from Stackoverflow, but without success. Perhaps this is also due to the fact that this element of the theme, which executes the dropdown, and my script do not harmonize.

The element for the trigger and the content of the container are two different elements.
(I have shortened the elements a little for easier presentation.)

**Toggle Element:**

```
<div id="bl-search-anchor-toggle" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="x-anchor-content">
     <div class="x-icon"><svg>...icon...</svg></div>
     <div class="x-anchor-text">Search</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Dropdown Content Element**
Everything under id="my-content" was added by me.

```
<div id="bl-search-dropdown">
  <div id="my-content">
     <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="https://...">
    <div>
      <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" tabindex="-1">
      <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_types" value="page">
    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="4"></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The java script i use:**

```
window.onload
{
  document.getElementById("bl-search-anchor-toggle").addEventListener("click", focus_search());
}

function focus_search()
{
  const s = jQuery("#bl-search-dropdown #s").get(0);
  s.tabIndex = '-1';     // Seems to be needed for chrome, firefox, safari too
  s.focus();
}
```